# How to add a sticky header to wordpress theme "Bota"?

Tags: css, wordpress

How can I change the coding in Bota so that the top bar already there is sticky? I have tried doing this

```
#topbar {
      position:fixed;
      background: #333;
      top:0;
      right:0;
     left:0;
     z-index:99;

}
```

and that just made it disappear completely. Any help would be appreciated.
edit: link to theme http://wordpress.org/themes/bota
I am using Wordpress 3.5.2

Comment: I have tried every other forum such as the specific ones on Wordpress but have not got any replies, I know its a very specific question but I have nowhere else to go and am really stuck! Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add `height` style

```
#topbar 
{
  position:absolute; /* or 'fixed' */
  background: #333;
  top:0;
  width: 100%; /* or 'left: 0; right: 0;' */
  height: 100px;
}
```

[**JSFiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/sW8h5/)

Comment: Thanks, I just changed position to fixed and it worked! Then I found a plugin that does it anyway but its giving me completely different trouble! Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the free WordPress plugin called Sticky Header http://wordpress.org/plugins/sticky-header/

It should work with almost any WordPress theme coded with best practices.